# Page permalink suffixed with -2

Tags: wordpress

I've deleted a page in wordpress admin. I've then created another page with the same name. Problem is that in the nav it's named mypagename-2. Even if I edit the permalink in the admin the -2 still remains. How do I re-create this page without the -2 appearing?!

Comment: Ah- just found it. If you empty the trash you can rename permalinks again!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to empty the trash. The old page is still in the database until you dump the trash.